# Select Muchos a Muchos SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas, relaciones, multiselect

Buens dias tengo la siguiente consulta SQL

```
 select
 eq.Codigo as "Código",
 eq.NoSerie  as "Número de serie" ,
 'Tipo de equipo: '+tipo.Nombre+' / '+'Marca: '+marca.Marca +' / '+'Modelo: '+ marca.Modelo 
 as "Descripción",
 from Equipos eq, MarcaEquipos marca, TipoEquipos tipo
 where eq.MarcaEquipos_id = marca.id and marca.TipoEquipos_id = tipo.id;
```

Dándome el siguiente resultado

| Código | No.Serie | Descripción |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | MX3333GHH5 | Tipo de equipo: ESCRITORIO / Marca: HP / Modelo: ELITEDESK 800 G1 SFF |
| 0002 | 1V666u633 | Tipo de equipo: ESCRITORIO / Marca: DELL / Modelo: OPTI 3470 |

mi consulta funciona bien, pero quisiera agregarle otro dato dentro de descripción
el cual seria el nombre del componente

aquí el problema, como un equipo puede tener varios componentes como lo son RAM, Procesador etc..
utilice una tabla intermedia

| equipos | EquipoComponente | Componentes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| NoSerie | (FK) equipos_id | Nombre |
|  | (FK) componentes_id |  |

en este caso puedo tener un registro equipos_id que se repita varias veces en esta tabla pero con distinto componentes_id de componentes distintos como o no tener ninguno

Ejemplo

| id | equipos_id | componentes_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

donde el equipo con id 1 seria el HP de la primer consulta componente 1 seria RAM y componente 2 seria Procesador

como puedo anexar esto en la primer consulta de mi alias "Descripción" para que cada componente por equipo quede concatenado en el campo

| Código | No.Serie | Descripción |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | MX3333GHH5 | Tipo de equipo: ESCRITORIO / Marca: HP / Modelo: ELITEDESK 800 G1 SFF Componente: RAM, PROCESADOR |
| 0002 | 1V666u633 | Tipo de equipo: ESCRITORIO / Marca: DELL / Modelo: OPTI 3470 Componente: RAM, SSD |

No se si tendrán alguna idea de como hacerlo tal vez un foreach pero se puede?
espero su retroalimentación gracias

Comment: Versión de SQL Server?

Comment: 2012 es la version